# Angular/Typescript regex function failing

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying out this function so that I can map ID's to values, but the regex part of the function is not working.

Here is the part of the function I am having issues with:

```
xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      result = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['cm:property']
      this.regex = `/${this.uiListElement[0].$.id}.${this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.id}/`;
      console.log(this.regex);
      let m;
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i].$.name)
        if ((m = this.regex.exec(result[i].$.name)) !== null) {
          console.log(m);

          m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
          });
        }
      }
```

When console.log'd:

`this.regex` is `/hl7_file_type_[0-9].msgtype/`

`result[0].$.name` is `hl7_site_code` but as you can see the first index which isn't a match is what breaks it.

I'm hoping in the `if` statement to match and the values.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code, until it is the absolute minimum code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @slartidan code reduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `.exec` on a string. If you want to dynamically create a regular expression, you need to use the `RegExp` class:

```js
this.regex = new RegExp('my_regular_expression');
```

Note that the leading and trailing `/` must be omitted.